# What functionality is provided with div element that isn't in section element?

Tags: javascript, html

I know that any `<div>` element are instantiated from `HTMLDivElement` constructor. But there isn't any special constructor for the `<section>` element; it's a general `HTMLElement`. So what functionality is provided with the `<div>` element that isn't in the general HTML element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Mozilla Developer Network docs on `HTMLDivElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement), the interface only provides a single obselete property, `align`, that is not inherited from `HTMLElement`.

Thus, the answer to your question is that `HTMLDivElement` used to provide additional functionality over its parent interface, but this functionality has become deprecated and thus the differences are no longer meaningful to developers designing websites today.

Comment: The difference in terms of the DOM is certainly meaningful to the thousands if not millions of sites that still rely on the align attribute. It is indeed no longer meaningful to authors building new sites today.